# Duplicated Http Request

Tags: angular

I know that a similar question was asked? Find that should use share() operator from RxJs 
Apply this solution but the error still exist

```
  addRequest() {
    const requestList = [];
    this._sharedService.selectedRequests.forEach((req) => {
      const id = req.id;
      const path = `Request/${id}`;
      requestList.push(this._apiService.put(path, req));
    });
    forkJoin(requestList).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

Put method in API service

```
put(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    const httpOpt = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain'
      })
    };

    return this.http.put(
      `${environment.API_URL}${path}`,
      JSON.stringify(body), httpOpt
    ).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors), share());
}
```

Also don't use **async** in html code

Comment: What is `the error`?

Comment: @Carsten same request is called two times

Comment: Are you sure it's not an `OPTION` request, then the `PUT` request ?

Comment: @Emilien two times is PUT request

Comment: have u tried to pipe the call (RxJS Pipe operator) and use shareReplay() RxJS operator inside?

Comment: In my project I'm using `countries$ = this.users.countries().pipe(
    publishLast(),
    refCount()
  );`. Maybe you can try.

Comment: @Emilien I try this I this for 3 requests. 1, 2 was canceled but third call second time